Different definitions of the cut locus
Let $(\mathcal{M},g)$ be a Riemannian manifold which is complete and connected. For any $(p,v) \in \mathcal{TM}$, let $\gamma_v$ denote the maximal geodesic starting at $p$ in direction $v$. The cut time of $(p,v)$ is defined as
\begin{align*}
t_\text{cut}(p,v) = \sup\{b > 0\ \vert\ {\gamma_v}\vert_{\lbrack 0, b\rbrack} \ \text{is minimizing}\}.
\end{align*}
In Jack Lee's book, the cut locus $\text{Cut}(p)$ of a point $p \in \mathcal{M}$ is defined as follows:
\begin{align*}
\text{Cut}(p) = \{\gamma_v(t_\text{cut}(p,v)) \ \vert \ v \in T_p\mathcal{M} \ \text{such that} \ t_\text{cut}(p,v) < \infty\}.
\end{align*}
However, multiple posts claim that $\text{Cut}(p)$ can be alternatively defined as the closure of the set of points $q \in \mathcal{M}$ such that there is more than one minimum length geodesic from $p$ to $q$, see for example answer 1 and answer 2.
I am looking for a proof (or a reference with a proof) supporting this claim. The paper cited in answer 2 does not contain a proof, and neither do the references therein. I failed to show this myself.
